# Mix [JsonExtensionData] with MissingMemberHandling.Error with JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

In order to avoid losing JSON properties when deserializating to a POCO that is missing members, I use the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute. Ex:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int Y { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _extraStuff;
}
```

That way, if I try to deserialize the following, I won't lose the `z` property:

```
{
  "y": 1,
  "z": "added in foo"
}
```

So far so good.

But in reality, I have a really deep object graph. So every POCO in the graph must use the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute. This is a little dangerous. As soon as I forget to add this in one of the class, doing a deserialization followed by a serialization will lose data. (the real use case is doing a HTTP GET followed by a HTTP POST and I want to be sure that I don't lose anything)

So, to be sure that I haven't forgotten any `[JsonExtensionData]` in my whole POCO object tree, I thought about using the following deserializer setting:

```cs
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error 
};
```

But then, if I try to deserialize the previous JSON, I get the following exception:

```
Could not find member 'z' on object of type 'Foo'. Path 'z', line 3, position 6.
```

This is a quite annoying, it complains about a field that has no member in the POCO but that is covered by the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute.

Is there a way to only raise errors **when data is actually data being lost** during the deserialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may mark your object with [`[JsonObject(MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore)]`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonObjectContract.cs#L51).  This will override the serializer setting:

```
[JsonObject(MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore)]
public class Foo
{
    public int Y { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _extraStuff;
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/erDRth).

Alternatively, you could create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that does this automatically:

```
public class MissingMemberContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (contract.ExtensionDataSetter != null && contract.MissingMemberHandling == null)
        {
            contract.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follow.  First cache a copy somewhere for performance:

```
static IContractResolver contractResolver = new MissingMemberContractResolver
{
    // Modify settings such as the naming strategy if required.
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
};
```

And then set in settings as follows:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ContractResolver = contractResolver,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error 
};      

var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, serializerSettings);

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Formatting.Indented, serializerSettings);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bfZ0Qy).

Note that MissingMemberHandling was added to to `JsonObjectAttribute` and `JsonObjectContract` in [Json.NET release 12.0.2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/12.0.2).  On earlier versions neither of the above solutions are available.

Honestly I'm a bit surprised this is necessary.

As an aside, if you're creating a custom contract resolver anyway, you could make [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateObjectContract.htm) throw for any object in your assembly or namespace that lacks an [`ExtensionDataGetter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_ExtensionDataGetter.htm) and [`ExtensionDataSetter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_ExtensionDataSetter.htm).  If you do that you'll be able to discover any types that lack a `[JsonExtensionData]` during unit testing.